# JS/Apps Script: How to pass object and object keys as parameters?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script, I want to loop through the data and write only specific keys into a sheet. I do not want to perform the looping operation in the main function, but instead want to pass it to another function, which will be utilized multiple times.

How do I make the following `print_data()` function work the way it is printing in the `main()` function?

```
function main() {

  const data = [{"key_1":10,"key_2":20,"key_3":30},{"key_1":40,"key_2":50,"key_3":60}];

  // Print data
  for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    const d = data[i];
    Logger.log([[d.key_1,d.key_3]]);
  }

  const keys = [[d.key_1, d.key_2]];
  print_data(data, keys);

}

function print_data(data, keys) {

  for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    const d = data[i];
    Logger.log(keys);
  }

}
```

Solution:

```
function test_main() {

  const data = [{"key_1":10,"key_2":20,"key_3":30},{"key_1":40,"key_2":50,"key_3":60}];
  const keys = ["key_1","key_3"];

  // print_data(data, keys);
  print(data, keys);

}

function print(data, keys) {

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
  sheet.clear();

  for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    arr = Array(keys.map(k => data[i][k]));
    sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,2).setValues(arr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the keys as strings, then use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the values corresponding to those keys for the current object.

```js
const Logger = console; // for demonstration
function main() {
  const data = [{"key_1":10,"key_2":20,"key_3":30},{"key_1":40,"key_2":50,"key_3":60}];
  const keys = ['key_1', 'key_3'];
  print_data(data, keys);
}
function print_data(data, keys) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(keys.map(k => data[i][k]));
  }
}
main();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what I was looking. How do I convert the loop, considering I need the counter and using `sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,2).setValues(data[i])` method to write values to each row?

Comment: @Shantanu I've converted it back to a regular index-based for loop,

Comment: BTW, can you show a separate example of mapping it for a nested array? For example, how can I map `key_1` and `sub_key` from the following? `const data = [{"key_1":10,"key_2":20,"key_3":{"subkey":30}},{"key_1":40,"key_2":50,"key_3":{"subkey":60}}];`

Comment: Ok, let me create a different question, as this helps in this use case.